# HTTP/1.1 vs. HTTP/2: Session Locking in PHP 7.1 and Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, session

`script1.php` is a "long running" script, here simulated with a sleep function:

```
session_start();
$_SERVER['abc'] = 123;
session_write_close();
var_dump(microtime(true));
sleep(10);
var_dump(microtime(true));
```

`script2.php` executes quickly:

```
session_start();
$_SERVER['abc'] = 456;
var_dump(microtime(true));
```

`script1.php` does not block `script2.php`, when simultaneously opened in a second tab, if Apache is configured to use HTTP/1.1:

```
Protocols http/1.1
```

**This is the desired behavior**.

Yet, when Apache is configured to use HTTP/2, with:

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

or, just:

```
Protocols h2
```

`script1.php` does block `script2.php` i.e. `script2.php` in the second tab is only executed once `script1.php` has terminated (after 10 seconds).

How does the HTTP protocol affect PHP's session locking mechanism?

How can the desired behavior be achieved with HTTP/2?

If anyone could shed some light on this situation, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Are you running PHP via php-fpm (network or socket?), mod_php, or some other manner?

Comment: Also, which version of PHP 7.1 and Apache 2.4 were you testing with?